# modeling an outcome that has a range from [-0.158 ; 1 ]

Tags: regression, data-transformation

I am trying to model a quality of life score that has a range [-0,158 ; 1], where values equal to one indicate the patient is fully healthy, values equal to 0 indicate the patient is dead, values smaller than 0 indicate a health state that is worse than death.

I assume general linear regression is not suitable since my response variable can always go outside the response range depending on the values of the covariates.

What is the suitable model parametrization to make sure that response stays always in the response range?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two questions and a comment. What do you want to do with your model? Is there a lower bound to your outcome, like -1, but you don't observe anyone that far down in your data? The scale seems strange to me in its non-monotonicity, unless there are some theological considerations, like eternal damnation. Usually, there is a spectrum from health to sickness and finally death.

Comment: in order to assess the quality of life of the patients, a 5 dimensional instrument is used. we ask the patient 5 questions : 1-mobility( do you have a problem with walking) 2-self care( do you have problems washing or dressing yourself) 3- daily activities( do you have a problem with daily activities) 4- pain/discomfort( do you have pain or discomfort) 5-anxiety/depression( do you feel anxious or depressive).
each question can be answered with a rating scale from 1 to 5. 
1 : no problems.
2 : a bit of problems.
3 : moderate problems.
4 : serious problems.
5 : not able to

Comment: Thus each patient can have a health state ranging from (11111)=perfect health till (55555)=worst possible. there was a paper by Irina Cleemput, which valuated those score via regression and come up with a way to create a quality of life score.
that score is equal to 1 if the patient is fully healthy, equal to 0 if the patients is dead, and values less than 0 indicate a health state that is worse than death.

Comment: to answer your question : the upper bound of my outcome variable which is the quality of life score is 1.( if all questions answered with 11111)
the lower bound is -0.158.( if all questions answered with 55555)
all I want now is a reparameterization for this outcome variable ( score) so I can model it properly.

Comment: another note : in my data i do observe patients with the lowest possible score(1) and highest possible score (-0.158)

Comment: It would be helpful to include the relevant content from the paper here, as well as a reference to the paper.

Comment: Cleemput I. A social preference valuations set for EQ-5D health states in Flanders, Belgium.
European Journal of Health Economics 2010;11(2):205-13.

Comment: van Hout B, Janssen MF, Feng YS, Kohlmann T, Busschbach J, Golicki D, et al. Interim Scoring for
the EQ-5D-5L: Mapping the EQ-5D-5L to EQ-5D-3L Value Sets. Value in Health 2012 Jul;15(5):708-
15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do:

- Step 1. Transform [-0.158, 1] to [0, 1] with a simple linear transformation.
- Step 2. Transform [0, 1] to [$-\infty, \infty$] by taking the logit.
- Step 3. Check normality and do linear regression.
- Step 4. Convert back to [0, 1] and then to [-0.158, 1].